# Cant take user input with PHP using isset without object not found error

Tags: php

I am trying to learn simple php and using user input. But when ever i run the code below, i always get this error:

(Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404

localhost
Apache/2.4.17 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2d PHP/5.6.14)

From what ive read, this code should work. Im using xampp if that changes anything. I also have to do the HTML and PHP all on one sheet.

```
 <?php
if(isset($_POST['username']))
 echo "<h1>Hello " . $_POST['username'] . "</h1>";
  ?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Enter your name</h1>
<form method="post" action="handler.php">
<input type="text" name="username">
<input type="submit">
  </form>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: is the above file named "handler.php", your calling it via `http://...handler.php`

Comment: Can you provide the file path of your HTML file? (Should be something like: `C:/xampp/htdocs/..`) and URL that you are targeting? (should be something like `http://localhost/..`)

Answer (score 0):

### HTTP response codes

Check out this list: [HTTP response codes | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Response_codes). Your error simply say the page is not found. Why?

You're opening PHP file, e.g. index.php. There you place `<form></form>` with buttons, checkboxes, inputs etc. You select request method (`GET`, `POST`), target of action (another URL, another file).

I assume, your code is placed in `index.php` file when your form redirect to not existed `handler.php` file. If this is not true, try to fix URL to file. Instead of `handler.php`, use `/handler.php`.